# Can't find 'Generate Sign APK' on Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I just updated to Android Studio Giraffe, I'm trying to generate a signed APK for an app built in Flutter, but I can't seem to find the Generate Signed APK option under Build.

The options under Build is an additional drop down for Flutter, then under that is: Build AAR, Build APK, Build App Bundle and Build iOS and Web.

There's also a Deploy Module to App Engine option that throws a 'project does not contain any app engine modules' error.

Any help?

I tried generating app bundle but it simply just generated the bundle without the prompt to create a signing key.

I tried to use powershell too but it got complicated because of some java errors.